# Should input POJOs be assigned to an agent field (variable) and define other fields (variables)?

Tags: java, anylogic, pojo

In Anylogic, I use a POJO class that keeps the input data of an agent. I instantiate a POJO object for an agent and feed it to that agent as a parameter. After I instantiate a POJO object for an agent, fill the POJO with the agent's input data, and feed it to the agent as a parameter, there are 3 ways to process that parameter:

1. **Assign Parameter to Agent Field and Use Getters:** Assign the POJO parameter to an agent field and use getter methods to retrieve specific data from that field. This approach allows you to encapsulate the POJO data within the agent while providing controlled access to the data through getters and promotes information hiding.

   ```
   public class MyAgent extends Agent {
       private InputData inputData; // Assuming InputData is the POJO class

       public MyAgent(InputData inputData) {
           this.inputData = inputData;
       }

       // Example getter method
       public double getSomeValue() {
           return inputData.getSomeValue(); // Assuming getSomeValue() is a method in InputData
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Assign Parameter to Agent Field and Define Other Fields:** Assign the POJO parameter to an agent field, but you also define other fields in the agent to directly store relevant data from the POJO. This approach allows you to extract and store specific data from the POJO upfront, potentially providing faster access during simulation.

   ```
   public class MyAgent extends Agent {
       private InputData inputData; // Assuming InputData is the POJO class
       private double someValue; // Other field to store a specific value from the POJO

       public MyAgent(InputData inputData) {
           this.inputData = inputData;
           this.someValue = inputData.getSomeValue(); // Assuming getSomeValue() is a method in InputData
       }

       // Example getter method
       public double getSomeValue() {
           return someValue;
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Directly Assign Parameter Data to Agent Fields:** Directly assign specific data from the POJO parameter to corresponding agent fields without storing the entire POJO within the agent. This approach provides direct access to the necessary data while avoiding additional indirection.

   ```
   public class MyAgent extends Agent {
       private double someValue; // Agent field to store a specific value from the POJO

       public MyAgent(InputData inputData) {
           this.someValue = inputData.getSomeValue(); // Assuming getSomeValue() is a method in InputData
       }

       // Example getter method
       public double getSomeValue() {
           return someValue;
       }
   }
   ```

As we normally have data fields in the POJO that directly map to agent fields, the second or third approach may be more suitable. I am wondering what is the best practice inline with OOP principles in this context?

Comment: i would say that this is probably completely determined by programmer style and the context of what needs to be done, hence it's just about opinion and doesn't have a definitive answer.